# QT application with QList<QString> function "append"

Tags: c++, qt, qregularexpression

I'm trying to return a list of matches returned from a QRegularExpression to a QList with this code below:

```
QList<QString> list();
QString str ("something by the way");
QRegularExpression reA("pattern");
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = reA.globalMatch(str);

while (i.hasNext()) {
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
    if (match.hasMatch()) {
        list.append(match.captured(0));
    }
}

return list;
```

...But it shows me this errors:

```
/home/path/.../file:line# error: request for member 'append' in 'list', which is of non-class type 'QList<QString>()'
         list.append(match.captured(0));

/home/path/.../file:line#: error: could not convert 'list' from 'QList<QString> (*)()' to 'QList<QString>'
 return list;
```

How can i get it working, I've tried to cast into many types.

Comment: You are declaring `list` as a function of some sort? I don't think you meant to do this. See: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#append (You should also always show what steps you have taken to solve problems like this. I'd expect an IDE, for example, to point this out to you.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QList<QString> list();
```

It's actually a function. For a variable, you have to omit the parentheses; but this is confusing since you use usually the parentheses to pass arguments to the constructor.

It should be:

```
QList<QString> list;
// or
QList<QString> list{};
```

Answer (score 5):

try the following code please:

```
QList<QString> list;
QString str ("something by the way");
QRegularExpression reA("pattern");
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = reA.globalMatch(str);

while (i.hasNext()) {
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
    if (match.hasMatch()) {
        list.append(match.captured(0));
    }
}

return list;
```

Because it is possible to overload operator such as `()` in c++ it very complicated for your compiler to make the difference between a constructor without parameters and parenthesis operator.
Because of that if you want to call a constructor without any args don't put parenthesis `Qlist<QString> myList;`.

You can only put parenthesis when you are using *New* operator `QList<QString> *myList = new QList<QString>()`.

Parenthesis operator is used to make callable objects in C++, if you want to know more about it you can look at this [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable)